# Custom Lens - Viewport doesn't match render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, glass

I have a scene with a warped plane acting as a lens. I matched the camera to viewport, but the renders look too zoomed in, and the warping effect is different than in viewport.

**Viewport render:**
[image: Viewport]

**Renders:**
[image]

**Note:** I have tried messing with camera settings to no avail. Thank you for taking a look at the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: there is no blend file...

Comment: I apologize for that. The .blend file is now added!

Comment: not sure about your material, don't you want to directly plug the glass into the Output?

Comment: @moonboots I would think the same.

Comment: You are correct; the material is overcomplicated for this particular shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "Edited Lens" object has a *Solidify* modifier that is disabled in the *3D Viewport*. Without solidifying this object is just a plane, and in this case everything below is treated as if it was inside a big glass cube instead of a glass pane, because the IOR refracts the light while entering the plane from one side but not exiting on an opposing side.

If you enable the *Solidify* modifier in the viewport, the result looks exactly like the render. So the solution will be to deactivate the modifier for rendering as well - or simply delete it. If you don't want to see it neither in viewport nor in render, what good is it for?

Comment: Thank you very muh! I totally missed that. I am getting the results I want now.